# hibernate native query complex constructor mapping

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, sqlresultsetmapping, hibernate-native-query

Java, Spring Data JPA

I have 2 entities:

```
class Source {
  Integer id;
  String name;
}

class Item {
  Integer id;
  String name;
  Integer sourceId;
}
```

I need statistic native query result like this:

```
 select s.id source_id, s.name source_name, count(i.id) item_count
 from source s
 left join item i on s.id = i.source_id
 group by s.id
```

And i want to have result in Java object MyResult:

```
class MyResult {
  Source source;
  Integer itemCount;
  MyResult(Source source, Integer itemCount) {...}
}
```

The closest solution is using @SqlResultSetMapping like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "MyResultMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
             entityClass = Source.class,
                fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "source_id"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "name", column = "source_name"),
                }
        ),
        ... 
        ???
    }
)
```

OR

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "MyResultMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = MyResult.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "???"),
                    ???
                }
        )
    }
)
```

With second variant i can use something like this:

```
MyResult(Integer sourceId, String sourceName, Integer itemsCount) {
    this.source = new Source(sourceId, sourceName);
    this.itemsCount = itemsCount;
}
```

but i want it to automate with @SqlResultSetMapping... (because my real objects more complex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Data JPA it's better to use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to achieve you need, for example:

```
public interface SourceWithItemCount {
    Source getSource();
    Integer getItemCount();
}
```

Then in your Source repository create [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql) query method, like this:

```
public interface SourceRepo extends JpaRepository<Source, Integer> {
    @Query("select s as source, count(i) like itemCount from Source s left join Item i on i.sourceId = s.id group by s"
    List<SourceWithItemCount> getSourcesWithItemCount();
}
```

Important note is to use aliases for returned values (`s as source` etc.) it's allows Spring Data JPA to map them to projections properties.

`Join on <condition>` works from Hibernate version 5.1+ (if I'm not mistaken) so I recommend you to create classic [one-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) relation between your objects, like this, for example:

```
@Entity
class Source {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "source_id") private List<Item> items;
}

@Entity
class Item {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Then create [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html) query method supported by all versions of Hibernate (and other ORM providers):

```
@Query("select s as source, count(i) like itemCount from Source s left join s.items i group by s"
List<SourceWithItemCount> getSourcesWithItemCount();
```

Comment: thx for projection link and idea! it is looks like useful,

but my key problem is native query mapping (my entities without direct relations, and i can't use HQL)

Comment: @Elegant.Obj Hibernate 5.1+ supports join between unrelated entities, so you can use HQL.